# How do I authenticate users in shoudPerformSegueWithIdentifier and Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to create an authentication page in storyboard using IOS swift and Firebase. Here is my storyboardsegue declaration:
[image]

Then I'm using `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` to authenticate it. However, I also what to log the user in Firebase so my code is like so:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
if db.authData != nil {

  return true

} else {

  let email = emailTextField.text
  let password = passwordTextField.text

  db.authUser(email, password: password, withCompletionBlock: {
    error, authData in
    if error != nil {
      print(error.description)
    } else {
      print("logged in")
    }
  })

  return false
}
```

}

This code somewhat works but I would have to click the log in button twice because the first time logs in the user in Firebase, and the second time the  `db.authData` is no longer nil because the user is already logged in so it returns true. I don't want to have to click twice to log in, I just want to click once. I can't just put `return true` or `return false` in the `withCompletionBlock` either because the block returns void. How do I make this work?

Comment: Can you not make the `db.authUser` call synchronous?

Comment: or more simply, don't do this auth checking in `shouldPerformSegue`. You should call the auth method when a user click on "login" and within the authentication block, check for errors/nil and if all looks good you perfrom the actual segue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using current implementation you can't achieve this feature. You have two ways to do this:

1. Make the `db.authUser()` synchronous and return it's result
2. Instead of connecting the login button segue to next screen, add an IBAction method and implement the method like

```
@IBAction func login(sender : AnyObject?)
{
   let email = emailTextField.text
   let password = passwordTextField.text

   db.authUser(email, password: password, withCompletionBlock: {
     error, authData in
       if error != nil
       {
          print(error.description)
       }
       else
       {
          // Navigate to next screen
          // Start perform segue here
       }
    })  
}
```

Comment: I find that this works to log me in but it doesn't seem to call the `prepareForSegue` function so I can transfer some variables to the next controller. How can I make it so that when I navigate to next uiviewcontroller it would call `prepareForSegue` before that?

Comment: @user3904534: How you navigate to next screen ?

Comment: like this: `self.presentViewController(nextViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: @user3904534: Either you can set the data using `nextViewController` and set the properties you want. Like nextViewController.yourProperty = value; Or you can perform the segue programmatically self.performSegueWithIdentifier("YourSegueName", sender:self);

Comment: That works! Thank you very much! I did `nextViewController.myProperty = myProperty` before I called presentViewController.